# How to maintain curve tilt when adjusting height

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

How to maintain curve tilt when adjusting height.

I have a curve where the spiral maintains the **flat side down** when the **Z height** is **0** and the **curve tilt** is **45 degrees** (see red arrows).

[image: image 1]

When I change the **Z height** the curve twists and the flat side is no longer down but is twisting.  **How can I prevent this twist** so the **flat side is always down** when changing the **Z Height**? (see red arrows).

[image: image 2]

See attached Blender file

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

is this what you want?

[image]

[image]

so you just need to add the set curve normal before the set curve tilt node.

Comment: Yes Thanks!.....